# Summ vectors within sublists (operating on sublists within a list R)

Tags: r

I am attempting to sum up each vector contained within three sublists. I have tried to make a few lists. Using the split function generates numbered vectors within each sublist.

```
p <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1)

# Factors for below calulations
k <- c(10, 45, 34)
j <- c(12, 20, 20)
t <- c(1,2,3)

fun <- function (x) if(x-1==0) p[1:J[x+1]] else p[(J[x-1]+1):J[x]]
p1 <- lapply(t,fun)
fun <- function (x) split(p1[[x]],ceiling((seq_along(p1[[x]])/(k[[x]]))))
p2 <- lapply(t,fun)
str(p2) # Three sublists with different number of vectors associated. 

# Manually I could do. 
p2[[1]][[1]]

# Could also do 

expand.grid (x=t , y= )
mapply ( function (  p2[[x]][[y]]  ), x , y )
```

However I would like to write function or loop as to be able to add up the value of each sublist vector. I cannot find out how to write the required matrix via expand.grid as to use mapply as per the different length of the three sublists within the main list.

Any help is welcomed

Comment: Can you use `rapply` ... `rapply(p2, sum, how="list")`

Comment: @ user20650 - It works, how would you then go into applying this as to select via which.max for each sublist as to select the index of reference

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean... does this do what you want `rapply(p2, which.max)`. If not can you show what the expected outcome is for your list p2. Cheers